# State instantiation confusion amongst siblings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have example done in Ionic and UI-Router but I don't think this is a problem with Ionic but more on UI-Router specific.

I always assumed that **if switching state at the same level of hierarchy (siblings), the controller won't get reloaded in any case** unless you switch out to other branches. Look like I am wrong.

Here is an example: http://codepen.io/hawkphil/pen/GJxgvE?editors=101

**HTML**

```
  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
    <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
    </ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


  <script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

      <ion-tab title="Home" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/home">
        <ion-nav-view name="home-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      <ion-tab title="About" icon="ion-ios-football" href="#/tab/about">
        <ion-nav-view name="about-tab"></ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>

      </ion-tab>

    </ion-tabs>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Home">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact1">
            Fact1
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact2">
            Fact2
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact3">
            Fact3
          </a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/fact1.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Fact1">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact1">
            Fact1
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact2">
            Fact2
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact3">
            Fact3
          </a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/fact2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Fact2">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact1">
            Fact1
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact2">
            Fact2
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact3">
            Fact3
          </a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/fact3.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Fact3">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p>
          <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact1">
            Fact1
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact2">
            Fact2
          </a>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/fact3">
            Fact3
          </a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/about.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="About">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <h3>Create hybrid mobile apps with the web technologies you love.</h3>
        <p>Free and open source, Ionic offers a library of mobile-optimized HTML, CSS and JS components for building highly interactive apps.</p>
        <p>Built with Sass and optimized for AngularJS.</p>
        <p>
          <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/tab/navstack">Tabs Nav Stack</a>
        </p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>

  <script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.home', {
      url: "/home",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
          controller: 'HomeTabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.fact1', {
      url: "/fact1",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/fact1.html",
          controller: 'Fact1TabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.fact2', {
      url: "/fact2",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/fact2.html",
          controller: 'Fact2TabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.fact3', {
      url: "/fact3",
      views: {
        'home-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/fact3.html",
          controller: 'Fact3TabCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.about', {
      url: "/about",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.navstack', {
      url: "/navstack",
      views: {
        'about-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/nav-stack.html"
        }
      }
    });


   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/home");

})

.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  console.log('Home');

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
    console.log('State change from: ' + fromState.name + ' to: ' + toState.name);
  });
})

.controller('Fact1TabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('Fact1');
})

.controller('Fact2TabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('Fact2');
})

.controller('Fact3TabCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log('Fact3');
});
```

This is the tree of the states:

```
        Home
     /   |   \
Fact1  Fact2  Fact3
```

Below is the flow (open Console Log):

- I started with **Home -> Fact1 -> Fact2 -> Fact3**. Everything happens as expected to initialize all controllers.
- Then it got tricky from **Fact3 -> Fact1** (nothing happens) **-> Fact3** (again) **-> Fact2** (just to make sure no controller instantiated) **-> Fact3** (again, but **BOOM** Fact3 Controller now suddenly instantiated --> **WHY??**)

**console.log output**

```
Home
State change from: tabs.home to: tabs.fact1
Fact1
State change from: tabs.fact1 to: tabs.fact2
Fact2
State change from: tabs.fact2 to: tabs.fact3
Fact3
State change from: tabs.fact3 to: tabs.fact1
State change from: tabs.fact1 to: tabs.fact3
State change from: tabs.fact3 to: tabs.fact2
State change from: tabs.fact2 to: tabs.fact3
Fact3
```

So now I am confused more than ever:

1. **Why Fact3 got instantiated?**
2. **What is the exact rule of controller instantiate amongst sibling states now?**
3. **What is the best practice for controller initialization then? Since I have 2 scenarios: (a) init once and only once during app runtime, (b) re-init when coming back to the state every time regardless when and how the state was before**

Comment: This is similar to something I have seen before with Ionic and tabs. For some reason when set up in certain manners Ionic seems to crawl every possible tab. (There is an actual reason why and I've put my debug logs up on Ionic's forums as to what is happening but never got much traction). I have had luck with using a ui-sref instead of href for navigation though. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like view cache causing all of these.

`$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);`

http://codepen.io/hawkphil/pen/OVvzmg

Basically by default, ui-router would **REFRESH** all controllers siblings: http://plnkr.co/edit/OAB98MvP8NKmskcJkxtd?p=preview

So my original thinking was wrong (so are many other people).